# css and images are not loading?

Tags: xcode, hosting

I have a folder in my root directory that is `candyfive` and it has my `html website` that is properly working and a domain is pointing to it, I have a subfolder inside candyfive that is named "portal". It is an admin panel of the site with its own css and images.

The problem is that the site in candyfive folder is loading correctly but the site in portal is not loading any image or css.

The link of css in my portal admin site is

```
<link href="css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

What should I add in this code to make it work in subfolder ?

Here is the site structure :

```
candyfive/portal/index.php
candyfive/index.html       - is working fine
candyfive/portal/index.php - css and images not loading ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<link href="../css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

instead of:

```
<link href="css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

`..` Is used to go up in the directory tree stucture..